# Xamarin recuperar el valor de un Binding de un ListView de la capa xaml en la capa cs

Tags: c#, xamarin, listview, binding

Hola antes de nada gracias por vuestra ayuda y siento mi torpeza, acabo de empezar a programar y no se como salir de esta...

Os comento tengo Listview que se incrementa conforme doy de alta registros en la DB, al final de cada una de las líneas que sale he añadido un botón para poder hacer un Update de este registro en la DB:
Código del xaml:

```
                                <Label x:Name="IDS" Text="{Binding IDServicio}" IsVisible="False" />

                            <Frame Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Padding="3"   BackgroundColor="Gray"  CornerRadius="8">
                                <!--HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"-->
                                <Button  Text="Apuntarme a este servicio" x:Name="Apuntarme" Clicked="Entrar_Clicked_Apuntarme" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                            </Frame>
                        </Grid>
```

Que es lo que necesito, pues que cuando pulse al botón "Apuntarme a este servicio", el evento de "Entrar_Clicked_Apuntarme", me devuelva el valor que contiene el {Binding IDServicio}, en la capa de cs.

Código cs:

```
        public void Entrar_Clicked_Apuntarme(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {

    }
```

Se que esta vacío pero he borrado todo porque nada de lo que he probado me funciona...

he conseguido encontrar que la propiedad BindingContext tiene el valor que busco (en la variable IDServicio), pero no consigo poner ese valor en una variable del fichero cs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

GRACIAS :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La verdad si trabajas con una lista de objetos (que veo que es el caso) la manera más sencilla de salir de este tipo de problemas es obteniendo el `BindingContext` (Simil de DataContext en WPF), en este caso el `BindingContext` es un objeto de tipo `Servicio`, osea, el `ListView` contiene una lista de Servicios.

La solución es:
Al clickear el botón obtén el `BindingContext` del propio botón, así:

```
private void Entrar_Clicked_Apuntarme(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    Servicio item = (Servicio)btn.BindingContext;
    var valor = (int)item.IDServicio;
}
```

Si quieres puedes hacerlo de la manera "larga" y así puede ser más sencillo para ti, el resultado debería ser el mismo, y de hecho, yo lo hago así, que es obtener paso a paso los controles que contiene el item en el `XAML` y ordenarlos por jerarquía para obtener el `Grid` que contiene todo y sacar su `BindingContext` que es el objeto Servicio.

```
private void Entrar_Clicked_Apuntarme(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    Frame frame = (Frame)btn.Parent;
    Grid grid = (Grid)frame.Parent;
    Servicio item = (Servicio)grid.BindingContext;
    var valor = (int)item.IDServicio;
}
```

Espero lo entiendas, en palabras simples, todos los controles que estén en un item del `ListView` tienen un `BindingContext` que es el item mismo que se está representando y teniendo el item puedes obtener sus propiedades, un saludo.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por la solución y explicación, parece un proceso sencillo pero por mucho que busque no habia encontrado la solucion ni esa explicacion en ningun sitio.